# How to disable hover-click in Bionic with xfce4

Tags: 18.04, mouse, xfce

I have been running Ubuntu 18.04 with xfce4 for over a year IIRC. Just today it is starting to do hover-click. Windows are raised, menu options are taken, links are followed just because the mouse happens to dwell somewhere for a couple of seconds.

This is a native 18.04 installation. My other machine was upgraded from 16.xx and does not do this.

How do I disable this most annoying anti-feature?

Comment: You mean clicks happen without your actually clicking?

Comment: Try from a terminal, `mousetweaks -s` to shutdown the mousetweaks that controls the hover-click.

Comment: @DK Bose that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Terrance That seems to have done the trick. Thank you.